# Objective-c 引数、返り値なしのblockの実行方法

Tags: objective-c, クロージャ

引数、返り値なしのblockの実行方法が分かりません。

下記コードで引数なし、返り値なしのblockと引数あり、返り値なしのblockをテストしています。

```
- (void)test1:(void(^)(void))block {
    NSLog(@"test1呼び出し");
    (void)block;
}

- (IBAction)test1Tapped:(id)sender {
    [self test1:^{
        NSLog(@"ブロック実行");
    }];
}

- (void)test2:(void(^)(NSString *))block {
    NSLog(@"test2呼び出し");
    block(@"ブロックの引数");
}

- (IBAction)test2Tappeed:(id)sender {
    [self test2:^(NSString *string) {
        NSLog(@"ブロック実行: %@", string);
    }];
}
```

test2Tappedメソッドではtest2メソッドに付属しているブロックが実行されましたが
test1Tappedメソッドではtest1メソドに付属しているブロックが実行されませんでした。
SDKの`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`メソッドではtest1Tappedメソッドと同じように空のブロック`^{ }`でメソッド完了後の処理が記述できているので`test1`メソッドで同じことができてもおかしくないと思うのです。

原因および解決策わかる方いましたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このコードはblockそのものをvoidにキャストしているだけで、block呼び出しにはなっていません。

```
- (void)test1:(void(^)(void))block {
    NSLog(@"test1呼び出し");
    (void)block;
}
```

(引数のない)blockを呼び出したいのであれば、(空の)カッコが必要です。

```
- (void)test1:(void(^)(void))block {
    NSLog(@"test1呼び出し");
    (void)block();
}
```

Comment: `(void)` もいらないのでは？

Comment: @unarist その通りですね。あっても問題ないので触れませんでしたが、質問者さんは、引数あり戻り値なしの場合には`(void)`はつけておられないので一言追加した方が良かったかもしれません。